# What does "temporarily deleted" mean?

Tags: support, homework-and-exercises, answers

I can't find in the help, or by googling, the meaning of "temporarily deleting" from a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353711/which-bottle-of-water-absorb-most-heat-before-reaching-30c/353715#comment792575_353715)

> I'm temporarily deleting this in accordance with our homework policy. Please don't post complete answers to the underlying problem in homework-like questions.

To me it sounds like it's deleted for now, but will come back at some point later on, but that meaning sounds implausible to me.

Could someone point me point me out to the appropriate help page / explain it?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6300/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no SE help pages beyond the [Phys.SE homework policy page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/2451).

In practice, a temporary deletion usually last 2 weeks, but there is no official policy or commitment from the moderators.

If the answer is still deleted after this period, the poster may leave a reminding flag (or comment in the thread/chat).

Comment: It's normally impossible to comment on deleted posts, as I recall. A flag may be the more appropriate course of action.