# Answer deleted for being full answer

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises, answers

[Trying to figure out the potential energy of a hanging rope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544655/trying-to-figure-out-the-potential-energy-of-a-hanging-rope)

It is said that my answer was temporarily deleted. Now, I put a lot of effort into writing the answer and I'd like it restored, how should I edit it so that it will be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second part of the comment that comes with the close notice:

> I'm temporarily deleting this in accordance with our homework policy. Please don't post complete answers to the underlying problem in homework-like questions.

is self-explanatory.  You need to edit down your answer and take out some details, and then plead you case to reopen.

Comment: Or wait awhile and ping the moderator to ask for it to be re-opened. "Awhile" usually means "once the danger of somebody turning this in for homework passes," which is probably at least several weeks.

Comment: Echoing @tpg2114, because OP could easily consult the revision history, it's not enough/too late _to edit down your answer and take out some details._

Comment: [They didn't get the memo at *Mathematics*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31460/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-asking-broader-questions-and-if-mathematics-st#comment138470_31460)

Comment: @tpg2114 But isn't there technically always the danger of someone else with the same question finding the PSE post with an answer that has been re-opened, and thus using that for their homework?

Comment: @AaronStevens There is. I don't know that there is really anything we can do about that though -- our policy is a compromise between a lot of people over time, and "temporarily deleted" was the result of that. But it's left vague enough that we try to use our judgement on what is a reasonable "temporary" length of time.

Comment: @AaronStevens See [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10128/what-does-temporarily-deleted-mean?rq=1) for example. It's kind of the only guidance we've worked out.

Comment: @tpg2114 I've been on the receiving end of that and while it  *is* frustrating because the policy is not uniformly applied most of the blatant abuses are curbed and it's more or less working ok.

Comment: @tpg2114 Is there an option to reopen answers that contain solutions because of the reason stated in this post? Because a user might have worked hard on the answer? I guess I don't understand the motivation behind having an option to reopen a solution answer. PSE doesn't want to be a homework help site, so why allow solution answers to be reopened?

Comment: @aaronstevens The way we treat homework is specific to our site, so there are no tools in place to support that. The only mechanism is for the answer op to raise a flag after a sufficient amount of time passes and ask. As for why we do that, again, it's the result of a very long set of compromises - it's trying to walk the line between people who see value in excercises answered here and those who don't want to aid cheating. It isn't a perfect policy or a perfect system, but then again, few policies based on compromise are perfect.

Comment: @tpg2114 ... and you know in these days of online finals and so much plagiarism: hold the line.  If there is cause to undelete this question it can be re-examined later.

Comment: @AaronStevens For what it's worth, requests to restore "temporarily deleted" answers (like this one) nearly always happen right after the answer is deleted. For a user to wait a couple weeks and raise a flag happens so seldom that it's not a good starting point for shaping policy.

Comment: done I changed it

Comment: Note that this question is about an answer being _deleted_, not _closed_. Answers can't be closed or reopened, that only happens to questions.

Comment: @tpg2114 Is your aim to prevent OP from reading a complete answer, or anybody who come to the question? As recently my answer was deleted, but before getting deleted it was already read by OP (I know because OP commented on my answer). So, I think, keeping it deleted is of no use now as undeleting it now or in future is same. If your aim is to prevent anyone who come to the question, then undeleting it in future don't make sense. {PS - still, I have edited the answer, to just give hint.}

Comment: @TontyTon Ultimately, the goal would be for people [to follow the homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) by not posting complete answers. But, when complete answers end up posted, the next goal is delete them temporarily -- ideally before OP can read it/copy it down/etc.. Since we're trying to prevent somebody from just copying down the answer and turning it in, it's worth temporarily removing even if it seems they read it (because maybe they didn't copy it down yet).

Comment: Once it is no longer likely to be worth copying down and turning it in, it can be un-deleted and OP plus future readers can read it. But, we wait awhile to make sure it is no longer a viable way to cheat on a particular assignment.

Comment: @tpg2114 Can moderators not just hide the edit history of the particular answer after it is edited to comply with the homework policy?

Comment: @TontyTon Not easily. There is an option to [redact information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292008/when-to-redact-revisions), but it is specifically designed for offensive material or for PII. It isn't perfect, requires two moderators (one to redact and the other to approve), and is supposed to be reserved for serious issues.